# restore filtered state in angular controller when using back button?

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I have order list page with a list of items and a set of filter options ( order state, order number, and date ) at the top of the page to filter the items. The user can click an item to view a detail page for the item.

When the user is on a detail and clicks their back button, it returns to the list, but with the filter options reset to default.

after doing some research o know that I can do it with with the Url the problem is I don't know how . please help me with that.

my controller

```
    function searchOrders() {
    $scope.isLoading = true;
    model.noData = false;
    model.isSearch = true;
    model.orders = {};
    QaDashboardService.searchOrders(model.filterByNumber, model.status, model.startFrom, model.startTo)
        .then(function (orders) {
            if(orders) {
                $scope.isLoading = false;
                model.orders = orders;
            }
        }).catch(function (error) {
        $scope.isLoading = false;
        model.noData = true;
    });
}
```

QaDashboardService.js

```
     function searchOrders(orderNumber, status, startFrom, startTo) {
        service.data = [];
        var deferred = $q.defer();
        var orderCollection = service.db.collection("orders");
        if (orderNumber) {

            orderCollection = orderCollection.where("number", "==", orderNumber);
        }
        if (status && status != "*") {

            orderCollection = orderCollection.where("status", "==", status);
        }
        if (startFrom && startTo) {
            startFrom = new Date(startFrom).getTime();
            startTo = new Date(startTo).getTime();
            orderCollection = orderCollection.where("created", ">=", startFrom).where("created", "<=", startTo);
        }

        orderCollection.get().then(function (querySnapshot) {
            if (!querySnapshot.empty) {
                querySnapshot.forEach(function (doc) {
                    service.data.push(doc.data());
                    deferred.resolve(service.data);
                });
            } else {

                deferred.reject("no data");
            }
        }).catch(function (error) {

            deferred.reject(error);

        });


        return deferred.promise;
    }
```

my app.js

```
 .state('qa-dashboard.orders-list', {
        url: "/orders-list",
        module: "private",
        templateUrl: "app/qa-dashboard/orders/orders-list/orders-list.html",
        controller: 'OrdersListCtrl',
        role: ['admin', 'QA'],
        resolve: {
            "allOrders": ["QaDashboardService", '$rootScope', function (QaDashboardService) {
                return QaDashboardService.allOrders(40).then(
                    function (data) {
                        return data;
                    },
                    function (error) {
                        console.error("Error:", error);
                    }
                );
            }]
```

Answer (score 0):

i tried this way and the url change but the filterd list is gone , it's like someone refresh the page

i change the url in app.js to be like this

```
   url: "/orders-list/:pageName"
```

I applied this function in QaDashboardService.js

```
        function openPage (pageName) {
        $state.go('qa-dashboard.orders-list',{'pageName':pageName});


    };
```

i called it in search function

```
   function searchOrders(orderNumber, status, startFrom, startTo) {
        service.data = [];
        var deferred = $q.defer();
        var orderCollection = service.db.collection("orders");
        if (orderNumber) {

            orderCollection = orderCollection.where("number", "==", orderNumber);
        service.openPage(orderNumber);

        }
        if (status && status != "*") {

            orderCollection = orderCollection.where("status", "==", status);
        service.openPage(status);

        }


        if (startFrom && startTo) {
            startFrom = new Date(startFrom).getTime();
            startTo = new Date(startTo).getTime();
            orderCollection = orderCollection.where("created", ">=", startFrom).where("created", "<=", startTo);
        }

        orderCollection.get().then(function (querySnapshot) {
            if (!querySnapshot.empty) {
                querySnapshot.forEach(function (doc) {
                    service.data.push(doc.data());
                    deferred.resolve(service.data);
                });
            } else {

                deferred.reject("no data");
            }
        }).catch(function (error) {

            deferred.reject(error);

        });


        return deferred.promise;
    }
```

but it didn't work it 
i also tried $location and didn't work either